# Unit testing securesocial authentication for play2.3.x controllers in scala

Tags: playframework-2.3, securesocial

We are using securesocial module for authentication in our Play 2.3.x application.

I would like to unit test the controllers in my application that need securesocial authentication.The testkit is not available for the lastest version.

Can anybody provide me with a solution to send a fake authenticated request to all the methods in controllers using secure social authentication ?

Below given is one of the method in our app's controller  :

```
def list = SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
  val params = request.asInstanceOf[RequestHeader]

  val future = DeviceDAO.listAll(params)
  future.map(list => {
    Ok(ResponseBuilder.getResponseJson(params, Json.toJson(list.devices), list.totalItems))
  })
}
```

Currently we are unit testing our controllers by appending authtoken in our request header as below :

```
 "list is empty " in new WithApplication {
    val req = FakeRequest(GET ,"/v1/devices").withHeaders(
      "X-Auth-Token" -> authToken,
      "Content-Type" -> authcontentType
    )
    val home =  route(req).get
    status(home) must equalTo(OK)
    var items = contentAsJson(home) \ "items"
    items.as[JsArray].value.length must equalTo(0)
  }
```

Since this is not an ideal way to test the authentication , we would like to test using a proper fake authenticated request for the controllers. The older version of secure social provides a test-kit that can be used as :

```
"Access secured index " in new WithLoggedUser(minimalApp) {
val req: Request[AnyContent] = FakeRequest().
  withHeaders((HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")).
  withCookies(cookie) // Fake cookie from the WithloggedUser trait

val result = Application.index.apply(req)

val actual: Int= status(result)
actual must be equalTo OK
```

}

But this does not work for Play 2.3.x applications . 
So can some one tell me how to write unit test cases for the latest version securesocial authentication in the above manner for Play 2.3.x applcaition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are already unit testing it with play 2.3 and SecureSocial. Below you find our login util class and the WithAppLogin abstract we are using to perform the authentication with a POST request.

hope it helps.

```
package controllers.common

import org.specs2.execute.AsResult
import org.specs2.execute.Result

import play.api.test.{FakeRequest, WithApplication, Writeables, RouteInvokers}
import play.api.mvc.Cookie
import play.api.test.Helpers
import play.api.test.Helpers.cookies
import play.api.test.Helpers.defaultAwaitTimeout


object LoginUtil extends RouteInvokers with Writeables {

  val loginRequest = FakeRequest(Helpers.POST, "/auth/authenticate/userpass")
                       .withFormUrlEncodedBody(("username", "test@example.com"), ("password", "MyTestPassword"))
  var _cookie: Cookie = _

  def cookie = _cookie

  def login() {
    val credentials = cookies(route(loginRequest).get)
    val idCookie = credentials.get("id")
    _cookie = idCookie.get
  }
}

abstract class WithAppLogin extends WithApplication {
  override def around[T: AsResult](t: => T): Result = super.around {
    LoginUtil.login()
    t
  }
}
```

Test example

```
package controllers.admin

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.mutable._
import play.api.test.WithApplication
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.mvc._
import securesocial.core._
import play.Play
import controllers.common._
import play.api.test.Helpers.defaultAwaitTimeout

class AdminDashboardTest extends Specification {

  "Dashboard" should {

    "should be accessible" in new WithAppLogin {
      //setup
      val request = FakeRequest().withCookies(LoginUtil.cookie)

      //exercise
      val result = controllers.admin.index()(request)

      //verify
      status(result) must equalTo(OK)
      contentAsString(result) must contain("Welcome to the dashboard!")
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet .. but my application is throwing some internal error when I make use of the above code. Can you just  post even a sample test case for a method that makes use of above util class

Comment: @bhavya : updated my post with an example. Note that there is some custom code in it like `controllers.admin.index()`. This is a "SecuredAction" as given SecureSocial.

Comment: hey thank you so much , that was because of some database error and the code is working fine .. thanks a lot :)